# HTML CSS relative property

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have the following scenario.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: relative">
  <div id="header">
   <div id="logout" style="position: absolute"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How is the `logout` div positioned: is it relative to `wrapper` or to `header`?

Comment: Please use proper sentence structure, including periods, etc., when writing questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `#logout` div is relative to the div which has the property `position: relative` - your wrapper

---

A [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qGa69/) to prove it's correct and `#logout` is relative to `#wrapper`

Comment: @JoSo Your edit of the question is wrong. Please pay attention to this line *"I have Div called wrapper which has **position relative**"* Why did you put absolute there?